# Amplify's auto generated update mutation fails

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am able to create records for the model `Post` and read them too . My simple model:

`type Post @model {
  Name: String
  PostId: ID!
  Body: String
}`

I face issues when I try to update an existing record using the updatePost mutation. This is auto generated by amplify. In the graphql UI provided by AWS it requires the ID as a input rather than a filter. I can write a custom lambda function to resolve this but it seems such a waste of resource. Please advice if I am doing something wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default primary key "id" by using the directive @primaryKey.
docs: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#configure-a-primary-key